# Someone knows a xml2tex converter?

Tags: conversion, xml

I've already Googled it, without concrete success. So, I'd like to know if someone knows a converter from XML to TeX. Something "simple" as `latex2rtf`.

Comment: Could you elaborate whether you want to translate a specific XML-based document format (like FO or docbook) or general "xml data" to TeX. Maybe give an example of expected input/output?

Comment: http://getfo.org/texml/ perhaps? Comment, not an answer, as I've just found it myself and know nothing about it.

Answer (score 14):

XML is a file format not a language of any sort so asking for a general XML to latex is like asking for ASCII to latex. In general it depends what is in the XML file, one would not expect the same latex formatting for an XSLT program as a XHTML document, just because they both happened to use an XML syntax.

In general you need to specify the styling you want for the XML language in use.
XSLT is perhaps the canonical tool for this, however it is possible to get TeX to read the XML directly and apply formatting from a stylesheet. `xmltex` does this for LaTeX and ConTeXt has similar facilities built in.

For example, one specific translation: If you want to translate mathematics encoded in XML as MathML to LaTeX markup you could use the pmml2tex XSLT translation available from http://code.google.com/p/web-xslt/source/browse/trunk/pmml2tex

Comment: `\usepackage{smartass}`: "XML is ... not a language of any sort": Isn't XML called  "extensible markup language"?

Comment: True, but one man's metalanguage is another man's data: So yes it is a language of _some_ sort but not in the same sense as LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

I've developed an XSLT/XProc based library for converting arbitrary XML to TeX. It's not working out of the box but depends that you write a configuration for your XML. You can find code and documentation on GitHub. In the example directory are ready-to-use configurations for DocBook and DITA:

https://github.com/transpect/xml2tex

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to add some examples for CNXML (i.e. the language used by OpenStax [link](https://cnx.org/contents/WiNyiT7n@27.3:kPxRJVym)