# Converter europass.xml to tex

Tags: conversion

Do you know a converter, which transforms an europass.xml to an europass.tex file? 
`europecv` could be the documentclass for the europass.tex for instance. This means, it is not a question about 'show me a link for a documentclass'. There is no interest concerning rewriting my cv. That's the point.

Comment: Definitely not a complete answer, but I think this could be a starting point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61827/

Comment: The other I was trying to use a converter, which seemed very good but when it shown the result most of the columns were converted incompletely. I didn’t like the result. Now again looking for a better utility for <a href="http://www.datahouse.co.in/XML-Conversion.aspx"><b>XML Conversion </b></a>.

Answer (score 2):

To say it short: No.

The problem is that the europass cv has changed and the old `europecv` does not reproduce the new layout.

Best would be to write a new template for the new europass.